# Comparing two list values and finding only values from one list that do not exist in another

Tags: java, list, java-stream, set-difference

I have two list as shown below

```
List<Test> fisrtList= Arrays.asList(
                new Test(1, 1L),
                new Test(2, 3L),
                new Test(2, 4L)
                
                );
        
List<Long> secondList=Arrays.asList(3L, 5L);
//Find value of second  list that are not in first list
```

Expected answer from the comparision should be 5L as it is not in firstList.

Here is my Test class

```
public class Test {
    
    public Test(int id, Long idNo) {
        this.id=id;
        this.idNo=idNo;
    }

    private int id;
    
    private Long idNo;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Long getIdNo() {
        return idNo;
    }

    public void setIdNo(Long idNo) {
        this.idNo = idNo;
    }
    
}
```

How can I find the Long values from secondList that are not in the firstList?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use streams for this purpose the most efficient approach will look like this:

```
    public static List<Long> removeIntersection(List<Long> source, List<Test> valuesToRemove) {
        Set<Long> toRemove = toSet(valuesToRemove);
        return source.stream()
                .filter(num -> !toRemove.contains(num))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

```
    private static Set<Long> toSet(List<Test> valuesToRemove) {
        return valuesToRemove.stream()
                .map(Test::getIdNo)
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());
    }
```

The same result could be achieved by utilizing **removeAll()** and **retainAll()** methods from the Collection interface. These methods are optimized for ArrayList and perform in a linear time.

You just have to coerce your list of test objects to a list of Long and make a copy of the second list which gonna be mutated.

To demonstrate how these methods work let's consider the following example with lists of Integer values.

**removeAll()** will remove all elements contained in the given collection from this collection

**retainAll()** will retain only elements contained in both collections

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> source = new ArrayList<>(List.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9));
        List<Integer> valuesToRemove = new ArrayList<>(List.of(1, 2, 3, 4));
        source.removeAll(valuesToRemove);
        System.out.println("result of removeAll: " + source);

        source = new ArrayList<>(List.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9));
        List<Integer> valuesToRetain = new ArrayList<>(List.of(5, 6, 7, 8, 9));
        source.retainAll(valuesToRetain);
        System.out.println("result of retainAll: " + source);
    }
```

**output**

```
result of removeAll: [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
result of retainAll: [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do it

```
secondList.removeAll(firstList);
```

If you need `secondList` to not be modified you must make a deep copy first and use the deep copy instead of `secondList`.